# Validate domain name and ip address using regex in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have tried build app like whois domain tool site.

On form have one `text_field` and I want field only input with domain name and ip address.

Example domain name : domain.com (without `http://www.` or `https://www.` or `subdomain.`)

Example Ip address : 4.4.4.4

I want validate using regex, I have create this regex ([demo on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/L0FaNNBp5g))

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)
```

But that is not clean, www. or subdomain still accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this built in Ruby class [Resolv::IPv4::Regex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv/IPv4.html) for IP validation
and this [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) for domain names.

Answer (score 0):

**IP Adress:**

```
/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}(?:\-([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))?$/
```

Comment: Your regex for domain name still accepted http and https, I want without them and subdomain, only accept domain name and ip address in one field.